# Visual Studios Debug Error - VS Hosting Process

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

i have received the following error in VS 2010 after publishing an application using ClickOnce.

```
Error - The security debugging option is set but it requires the Visual Studio
hosting process which is unavailable in this debugging configuration. The
security debugging option will be disabled. This option may be re-enabled in
the Security property page. The debugging session will continue without security
debugging
```

Now every time i try to debug my project, when i try and run any database queries i get an "Unspecified Error". I have tried multiple different queries, all of which work on a new blank solution just not in my current one.

Note: i do not receive the "Unspecified Error" on the released version of the application just when debugging.

Not sure what i can do to fix it. It would appear to be something to do with my project setting, but i cannot see anything out of place.

Rob

Answer (score 1):

Bit late for an answer but should help others

Go to project property and under debug tab set or tick on "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process". This should fix the error you are getting.